# How to get the Original Value of Sin in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

Im assigning a value like this:

`var c = 1.2; var X = 0.3; var y = (c * Math.sin(X));`

I then make some changes to value y like:

```
y += 0.5;
```

How can i now get the new value of X using only y and c, such that it satisfies the original equation `y = (c * Math.sin(X))`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about trigonometry and not programming.

Comment: I'd keep the question. It is about not knowing the trigonometry functions in Javascript language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the function [Math.asin()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/asin)

```js
let c = 1.2;
let X = 0.1;
var y = (c * Math.sin(X));
console.log(c, y, X);

y += 0.5;
X = Math.asin(y/c);
console.log(c, y, X);
```

Comment: With limited info, I would guess that the OP is asking for the value of `X` in the original equation for the new value of y. I believe they should be able to do what they want, if they are aware of `Math.asin()` function. I could clarify in the answer if you wish.

Comment: Never mind, the OP edited the question to indicate that yes, they want the *new* value of `X` having changed `y`.

Answer (score 1):

If
`var y = (c * Math.sin(X)) + 0.5;`
Just use arcsine to get the value of X. Here's working:

y = c * sin(X) + 0.5

y - 0.5 = c * sin(X)

(y-0.5)/c = sin(X)
X = arcsin((y-0.5)/c))

Putting this back into code:
`var X = Math.asin((y-0.5)/c)`